# Updating Silverlight application - Only certain Projects, so what gets deployed?

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight-based solution (SLN) with many projects.  This application has been deployed before and I needed to make a change to two projects.

Do I only have to deploy the corresponding two DLLs or what else do I have deploy, e.g. do I also have to deploy the XAP?  I've looked at the Modified Dates and it seems that many projects/DLLs also got updated and I'm not sure why.  I want to deploy the minimal amount of files as possible.

I would've thought only those two DLLs are needed, but I guess I'm not too sure on the whole SL framework.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .NET library has been updated at all, then perhaps some of the resource/support DLLs have also been updated.  If that's the case then I think it would be safest to deploy all changed DLLs.

Also, I was under the impression that the XAP wrapped up all DLLs for the application, so I would think you would have to redeploy the entire XAP?  (If you change the extension of a XAP to .ZIP you can actually see which files are included in the XAP).

I've been out of the Siverlight loop for awhile though, so perhaps I am remembering things incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with Silverlight applications - everything is in the xap file (even resources and config files).  I would say you're going to have to deploy the xap - not just the dlls if you've just got the normal out of the box silverlight setup.

When Visual Studio packages the xap, it mostlikely will rebuild all the projects - not just the ones that have changed.  Like @ssawchenko mentioned, the xap is just a compressed file and you can change the extension to zip or use something like 7-zip to extract the contents.  That will allow you to verify the dates and/or versions of the dlls if you need to.

The other option with just deploying the dll's you need, means you would need to do the following:
1.  Get a the xap that is deployed 
2.  extract the files (by either using 7-zip or changing extension to zip and extracting)
3.  Replace the old dlls with the new ones
4.  Zip the files back up
5.  Change the extension back to xap

The only problem i can think of is if you miss a dependency change, but if it was a small change, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I've never seen the config files deployed as part of the xap, but that's probably due to how I have my sln and projects setup.  I have a solution with about 11 projects with  web services, server-side objects, client-side objects, Silverlight project, web project, etc.